# Sum of elements of the eigenvalue of a Markov Chain.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I need to probe the follow lemma

**Lemma 2**  if $\vec{v} = (v_i)^n_{i=1}$ is a eigenvector of the markov matrix $M$ asociate to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| < 1$, then $\sum^n_{i=1}v_i=0$.

Before this lemma I probe that

**Lemma 1** If $M$ is a Markov matrix $n x n$ and $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ \vec{0} \}$ , then $||M\vec{v}|| \leq ||\vec{v}||$.

How can I probe the first line (lema 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M\equiv(m_{ij})$ be a nonnegative matrix whose columns sum to one.
Let $v$ be an arbitrary column vector. Then, denoting by $e$ the column vector of all ones,
$$
e^{\intercal}Mv=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}m_{ij}v_{j}=\sum_{j}\sum_{i}m_{ij}v_{j}=\sum_{j}v_{j}=e^{\intercal}v.
$$
By induction, $e^{\intercal}M^{k}v=e^{\intercal}v$ for any positive integer $k$.
Next, let $w$ be a (right) eigenvector associated to an eigenvalue $\lambda<1$ of $M$.
Then,
$$
\lambda^{k}e^{\intercal}w=e^{\intercal}M^{k}w=e^{\intercal}w.
$$
Taking limits with respect to $k$ on both sides,
$$
0=e^{\intercal}w=\sum_{j}w_{j}
$$
as desired.